# Use OAuth2 .der token as Authorization header in curl PUT statement

Tags: curl, oauth-2.0, apache-pulsar, der

I think I need to decode my `.der` file to use as a public key, but I can't find a `cli` command to do this.

I'm getting the error `<h1>Bad Message 400</h1><pre>reason: Illegal character CNTL=0x2</pre>0`

```
CLUSTER=standalone
TENANT=sandbox
NAMESPACE=integration_test
AUTHORIZATION=$(cat /tmp/event-platform/oauth2_public.der)

# Create tenant
curl -L -X PUT "http://localhost:$HOST_PULSAR_PORT/admin/v2/tenants/$TENANT" \
    --header "Authorization: Bearer $AUTHORIZATION" \
    --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
    --data-raw "{\"allowedClusters\": [\"$CLUSTER\"]}"

echo $?
```

Answer (score 0):

Well a DER file contains binary characters so you should encode it before sending:

```sh
AUTHORIZATION=$(cat /tmp/event-platform/oauth2_public.der | base64)
```

A certificate file is not a bearer token though. If it is a client certificate credential, then maybe consider this type of syntax for sending it:

```sh
curl -s -X POST someUrl \
--cert ./certs/example.client.pem \
--key ./certs/example.client.key \
--cacert ./certs/root.pem
```